# Unable to wire in dependency using MockBean in WebMVCTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I have a controller class:

```
public class Controller {

    private final IProcessor processor;

    public Controller (final ProcessorFactory factory) {
        this.processor = factory.getInstance();
    }
}
```

A Factory class to provide the different instances of IProcessor:

```
@Component
public class ProcessorFactory {

    private final Dep1 dep1;
    private final Dep2 dep2;

    public ProcessorFactory (final Dep1 dep1,
                                final Dep2 dep2) {
        this.dep1= dep1;
        this.dep2= dep2;
    }

    public IProcessor getInstance() {
        if (...) {
            return new ProcessorA(dep1, dep2);
        }
        return new ProcessorB(dep1, dep2);
    }
}
```

In my mockito test class where I use Junit5, I am not able to instantiate the `IProcessor` member and is null:

```
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ProcessorFactory  processorFactory ;

    @MockBean
    private IProcessor processor;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {       
        when(processor.process(any(Request.class), any(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(new BlaBla("Test", "Test"));

        String request = ...

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/test/test").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(request))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }

}
```

I am not sure I am using MockBean correctly. Basically I want to mock both the Factory and the Processor.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to call a mocked method (`getInstance()`) during Spring context initialization (inside the `Controller`'s constructor), you need to mock the said method in a different way. The mocked bean has to be not only provided as an existing object, but also it should have it's mocked behavior defined.

Addtionally, `IProcessor` implementations are not configured as Spring beans, so Spring will not inject them - `ProcessorFactory` calls `new` explicitly and creates the objects without Spring involvement.

I've created a simple project to reproduce your problem and provide a solution - you can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/tree/63382047) if you want to check if the whole thing is working, but here's the most important test snippet (I've simplified the methods a bit):

```
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
class ControllerTest {

    private static final IProcessor PROCESSOR = mock(IProcessor.class);

    @TestConfiguration
    static class InnerConfiguration {

        @Bean
        ProcessorFactory processorFactory() {
            ProcessorFactory processorFactory = mock(ProcessorFactory.class);
            when(processorFactory.getInstance())
                    .thenReturn(PROCESSOR);
            return processorFactory;
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test1() throws Exception {
        String result = "this is a test";
        when(PROCESSOR.process(any()))
                .thenReturn(result);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/test/test")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content("{}"))
               .andDo(print())
               .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
               .andExpect(content().string(result));
    }

}
```